# Manual rectangular selection of items in QCustomPlot

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I'm working on a simple GUI with plot where you can set some x and y ranges. How can I select all items from all graphs on the plot that are within those ranges?
I was trying to reproduce the same algorithms that are run on [mouse rectangular multi range selection](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/dataselection.html) but I have not succeed. I hope there is some easier way that I am missing.

Example:[image]

Lets say that A and B are a pair of QCPRanges:

```
QCPRange A = QCPRange(2,4);
QCPRange B = QCPRange(1,8);
```

I would like to mark points on the plot that are within A and B ranges.

I am looking for some clues and tips to follow, not really a full copy-paste ready code.

Comment: Show the code you've tried

Comment: @eyllanesc I added my solution. Any better ways are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted by:

1. getting all records from all graphs by iterating all `data()` for each graph in `plot->getAllGraphs();`
2. checking QCPRanges if they contain every single data point
3. building QCPDataRanges based on indexes which meet QCPRanges requirements
4. building QCPSelection out of QCPDataRanges.
5. setting appropriate selection for every graph in the loop.

> Note: To make it work interaction `QCP::iMultiSelect` must be set for the plot. Also you need to `setSelectable(QCP::stMultipleDataRanges)` for every graph. Otherwise you might get an unwanted behavior as a result of selection.

Not really the most optimized way in the world but I couldn't think of anything better without rewriting part of the lib. Any better ways are welcome